# Selenium: click next till the last page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath, beautifulsoup

I am creating a web scraping tool using BeautifulSoup and Selenium. I am scraping a community forum where I am able to scrap the first web page of a particular thread. Say, for example, for the following thread: https://www.dell.com/community/Optiplex-Desktops/dell-optiplex-7000MT-DDR5-Ram-campatibility/m-p/8224888#M61514
i can scrap only the first page. I want to scrap all of the pages (in this case 3) and display the content.

The following code scraps the first page:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, ElementNotVisibleException


url  = "https://www.dell.com/community/Optiplex-Desktops/dell-optiplex-7000MT-DDR5-Ram-campatibility/m-p/8224888#M61514"

result = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")


date = '01-19-2023'
comments = []
    
comments_section = soup.find('div', {'class':'lia-component-message-list-detail-with-inline-editors'})
comments_body = comments_section.find_all('div', {'class':'lia-linear-display-message-view'})
 
for comment in comments_body:
    if date in comment.find('span',{'class':'local-date'}).text :
        comments.append({
            'Date': comment.find('span',{'class':'local-date'}).text.strip('\u200e'),
            'Board': soup.find_all('li', {'class': 'lia-breadcrumb-node crumb'})[1].text.strip(),
            'Sub-board':soup.find('a', {'class': 'lia-link-navigation crumb-board lia-breadcrumb-board lia-breadcrumb-forum'}).text,
            'Title of Post': soup.find('div', {'class':'lia-message-subject'}).text.strip(),
            'Main Message':  soup.find('div', {'class':'lia-message-body'}).text.strip(),
            'Post Comment': comment.find('div',{'class':'lia-message-body-content'}).text.strip(),
            'Post Time' : comment.find('span',{'class':'local-time'}).text,
            'Username': comment.find('a',{'class':'lia-user-name-link'}).text,
            'URL' : str(url)                           
            })
        
df1 = pd.DataFrame(comments)
print(df1)
```

I have tried the following:

```
next_page = driver.find_element("xpath","//li[@class='lia-link-navigation lia-js-data-pageNum-2 lia-custom-event']")
next_page.click ()
page2_url = driver.current_url
print(page2_url)
```

this is specific just for page 2.

However, i want this for all subsequent pages. And if there is only one page continue to execute next statement.
By using the above code i'm trying to get the URLs for the subsequent pages which i will add to list of urls that need to be scraped. Is there any alternative way to acheive this?

Comment: however, there is another issue I've ran into. One of the pages i was scraping does not have a text attribute for the username field. How do I go about that?

Comment: In that case what does `comment.find('a',{'class':'lia-user-name-link'}).text` return? An empty list or None?

Comment: It returns None. and the execution stops

Comment: Just before `comments.append(...)` put this `username = comment.find('a',{'class':'lia-user-name-link'}).text` then inside the dictionary replace `'Username': ...` with `'Username': username if username else '*missing data*'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scrape all the pages you can add a simple `while 1` loop which is broken when the button `Next Page` disappear.

```
while 1:

    print('current page:', soup.select_one('span[aria-current="page"]').text)

    comments_section = ...
    comments_body = ...
     
    for comment in comments_body:
        ...

    # next_btn is a list
    next_btn = soup.select('a[aria-label="Next Page"]')

    # if the list is not empty...
    if next_btn:
        url = next_btn[0]['href']
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")
    else:
        break
```

Comment: hi. so i used the same code for this page: "https://www.dell.com/community/Blogs-Podcasts/Proven-Professional-Program-A-New-Certification-Framework/ba-p/8362115/page/2?ref=lith_popular". For some reason, even though the aria-label is not in english (it is : Nächste Seite), it gets clicked which brings it back to the same page. and it gets stuck in an endless loop. how do fix this?

Comment: @NApStor I think because both "Previous" and "Next" buttons have the same `aria-label` look [this gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQtuH.gif) where I show this fact. You can solve this problem by replacing the definition of `next_btn` with `soup.select('li[class*=lia-component-next]>a')`